"Famous award" - "on ships"
What figure should replace the question mark?



Well, if this one isn't a doozy for the colour blind..

@Bass I have updated my answer to make it easier for those with visual difficulties.


 The missing letter is E (the last letter in Semaphore):



 The red lines in the puzzle represent the flag positions used in spelling out the word Semaphore in the Semaphore signalling system.


You have the same answer, I see. But perhaps you could include some more info about how it's derived?

@Stiv Good idea!  Done.

Well done, since you answered just before @Stiv I'm giving the tick to you

The question mark should be replaced by:

 

 i.e. the middle symbol from the top row.

Because if you focus just on the red lines:

 Row by row, these are the letters SEM, APH, and OR? in flag semaphore. To complete the spelling of the word SEMAPHORE, we need another 'E' so we should use the middle symbol from the top row one more time.



As for the title:

 semaphore is used to communicate between ships. Moreover (as prompted by the OP in comments), the pattern on the flag traditionally used in such signals - as in the diagrams above - is the international maritime signal flag representing 'O', with yellow and red sections either side of the diagonal. And 'O' in the NATO phonetic alphabet is 'Oscar', a 'famous award'.


Image source: Wikipedia


NB All I've got on "famous award" is that 'it sounds a bit like it'... Surely that can't be it?

Well done, I had a strong feeling this would be solved fast. Had another idea on how to present it but felt it was too complicated, should've went with that one instead.  And the title was refering to "Ofpne" "synt".

@Prim3numbah Oh, I see - because of the pattern on the one traditionally used; got it.
